# How to stop loop using character input without pausing loop

Tags: c++, loops, opencv, raspberry-pi, wiringpi

Good day,

I am trying to create a program that obtains orientation data from Sensors then uses that in a PID control algorithm to create corresponding PWM signals. I would like to be able to stop the program by pressing enter. I tried using opencv's waitKey(); however it does not accept my keyboard inputs. I also tried cin.get(); but it pauses my loop which creates a problem. My pwm would not get refreshed once the quadcopter changes orientation. I tried researching other methods however I could not get them to work. Here is a sample of my code using the two methods mentioned above.

Using cin.get():

```
using namespace std;

int main(void){

    while(1){
        /* get orientation data */

    /* output corresponding pwm */

    //Press enter to stop loop
        if(cin.get() == '\n'){
            /* Stop Pwm */ 
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using waitKey();

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(void){

    while(1){
        /* get orientation data */

        /* output corresponding pwm */

        //Press ESC to stop loop
        int key = waitKey(33){
        if(key == 27){
            /* Stop Pwm */ 
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I already found the answer, waitkey requires a dummy window to be open for it to accept keyboard inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way of querying the current state of the keyboard, which C++ does not provide natively.  In the past I have used [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) for this exact thing.  I like SDL because it is simplistic in nature, and is entirely written in C.  There is an example on the SDL wiki that demonstrates [detecting keyboard state](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryKeyboard%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29) that allows you to detect if a button is being held down.

Edit: SDL can be put on to a Raspbian Pi.  I found an example setup [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=58180)